# Is it possible to redirect to service console case record page instead of standard one in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to redirect to the case record I have created in lwc in the service console, instead of the standard case record page.

Is that possible to achieve in lwc at all? I have searched the documents but haven't got a clue yet.

Comment: If you are already in console and navigate, it opens in console as tab/subtab itself... is this what you are asking? or is it something else?

Comment: @salesforce-sas What I am trying to find out is: 1, is it possible to start from outside the service console? 2, is openTab() available for lightning web component? And is it okay to invoke it outside the console?